# When I drive at 80 kmh the whole car shakes violently

Tags: suzuki, vibration

I have a Suzuki Jimny 2007 model. When I drive at 80 kmh, the whole car shakes violently. It has the same vibration when the speed comes back untill 50. I spoke to my garage guy and as he said I polished my king pins. After some time the same vibration started again. I could not find the reason for this problem from any of the garage guys. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Jimny, then this is sadly expected. There are stories of people replacing the [gearbox mount](http://www.bigjimny.com/index.php/forum/7-jimny-technical/385-bad-vibration-solved) to resolve the issue, however I never got that far with my Jimny.

I had replaced a number of bushings, got an alignment, and new alloy wheels, however the shaking was still there - just far less pronounced. Like you, the vibrations were fairly violent at high speeds

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by a worn shock absorber or a broken control arm. My guess is the shock absorber. How old is the car and how many miles/kilometers has it done?